# How to do authentication with Node.js, Express and Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, passport.js

I've made simple nodejs application by using nodejs+express+angular. Now I want to make user authentification. I want to  session handling by using sequelize. Can you advise Simple example which include login/logout and home page using sequelize?

Answer (score 1):

A Google search produces:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vDdJBpOhTNo
2. https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-node-js-developer-course/learn/v4/content - this is a great tutorial that explains and demonstrates exactly what you are looking for!

Comment: I mean I didn't ask it so really I can't